# Why orientation-preserving homeomorphisms in definition of Mapping Class Group

Tags: general-topology, mapping-class-group

I am currently studying mapping class groups, and would like to know why one uses orientation-preserving homeomorphisms in their definition. I read in 'A Primer on Mapping Class Groups' by Benson and Farb that there are all sorts of replacements one can make, e.g. diffeomorphisms instead of homeomorphisms, isotopy instead of homotopy, but one always uses orientation-preserving maps. Is there a special reason one does that?

Maybe this hasn't to do with only mapping class groups either. Is there a general reason why one would only consider orientation-preserving maps?

Comment: It's a convenience for many of their arguments and (for orientable surfaces) the orientation-preserving mapping class group is an index 2 normal subgroup of the full mapping class group, so one doesn't lose a lot of information.

Comment: It is primarily because of connections to the theory of Riemann surfaces. The orientation-preserving mapping class group acts biholomorphically on the Teichmuller space, the quotient is the classical moduli space (or orbifold, to be precise). If you allow orientation-reversing mapping classes, you loose this. Also, every orientation-preserving mapping class is realized by a quasiconformal maps; this is not so if you reverse orientation. If you care about algebra or topology only, there is no reason for this restriction; but, as Mike said, the difference is minimal.