# Why use orientation-preserving diffeomorphism (instead of all diffeo's) in the construction of the moduli space of a Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, moduli-space

The question is basically in the title, but I want to make it more precise:

Given an oriented Riemannian 2-manifold $\Sigma$ one can take a quotient of the set
$$
\mathcal{M}_+(\Sigma)=\{~c~\mid (\Sigma,c)\text{ is a Riemann surface for a given orientation on }\Sigma\}
$$
by the action of
$$
\text{Diff}_+(\Sigma)=\{~f~\mid~f:\Sigma\to\Sigma\text{ is an oriantation-preserving diffeo}\}
$$
via
$$
\mathcal{M}_+(\Sigma)\times\text{Diff}_+(\Sigma)\to\mathcal{M}_+(\Sigma),~(f,c)\mapsto f^*c
$$
to obtain the moduli space
$$
M(\Sigma)=\mathcal{M}_+(\Sigma)/\text{Diff}_+(\Sigma).
$$
I understand that one aims to understand (some of) the structure of $\Sigma$ by studying $M(\Sigma)$. But doesn't the space $\mathcal{M}(\Sigma)/\text{Diff}(\Sigma)$ contain the same information on $\Sigma$ (without the subscripts they are just the set of all complex structures/group of all diffeo's)?

As far as I understand, for any complex structure $c$ there exists precisely one complex structure $\bar{c}$ such that $\text{id}:\Sigma\to\Sigma$, regarded as $\text{id}:(\Sigma,\bar{c})\to(\Sigma,c)$, is antiholimorphic. But this somehow makes the distinction between $c$ and $\bar{c}$ obsolete and a more 'natural' way to go would be to identify them as well and study $\mathcal{M}(\Sigma)/\text{Diff}(\Sigma)$ instead. Or is this somehow an 'uglier' space?

Google gave me some reference that in some case the moduli space consists of two connected components exchanged by complex conjugation, suggesting that this is generally not the case (however, lacking experience on the topic I found that article hard to read and I don't understand the precise setting). Also I found a reference which aims to generalize the subject to 'Klein surfaces' (for non-orientable Riemannian 2-manifolds), in which the moduli space is indeed $\mathcal{M}(\Sigma)/\text{Diff}(\Sigma)$ for the sake of having no $\text{Diff}_+(\Sigma)$. At third I found this SE-[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410151/why-orientation-preserving-homeomorphisms-in-definition-of-mapping-class-group) but this doesn't really help me any further - it merely points on the connection to the Teichmüller space but then the question arises again.

I lack intuition in the subject and would appreciate if anybody could tell me why we do not identify a complex structure $c$ with its 'conjugate' $\bar{c}$.

Comment: Your definition is not quite right. Where did you find it? I suggest you read some standard textbooks on the subject.

Comment: I took it from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304020808727828 (section 4.3)

Comment: I think I know what you mean, in this reference $\mathcal{M}(\Sigma)$ is already the space of those complex structures which agree with the orientation. But does that mean that all complex structures modulo all diffeo's is the same as all complex structures for a given orientation modulo orientation-preserving diffeo's?

Comment: Yes, there is a natural homeomorphism between the two quotients. The main problem with the definition you gave though is lack of extra topological and analytical structure on these moduli spaces: You are treating them simply as sets, which is wrong. I do not know who wrote this article and do not have access to it, but I can only repeat my suggestion: read a textbook on the subject (there are many).

Comment: Okay, now the definitions should be right, are they? The reference above is from  Mika Seppala - Geometry of Riemann Surfaces and Teichmuller Spaces. I didn't realize it's not open source, sorry for that.

Comment: Also I found A- J- Tromba - Teichmüller Theory in Riemannian geometry, where the author defines (on page 10) the moduli space as the "all complex structures" modulo "orientation-preserving diffeo's". So this is a different notion of moduli space, right? (this was the version I had before editing)

Comment: So can you maybe point me on some "standard textbooks"? Apparently for this problem the two references seem to do it a bit different and do not explain too much. Also picking some random third book may also go quite bad, from my experience.

Comment: Sure, you *can* bring in antiholomorphic maps. But why bother? The theory of holomorphic maps is so nice without having to muck up things with antiholomorphic maps. And, as you say, nothing is gained or lost by bringing them in.

Comment: So the long term goal is to understand the Seppala approach to the non-orientable case, where you must somehow take them into account. So in "nothing is gained or lost by bringing them in" you say that "all structure" mod. "all diffeo's" is the same space (i.e. set + structure) as "all structures w.r.t. given orientation" mod. "all orientation-preserving diffeo's", do I understand this correct? But why is it then that some authors appear to define the moduli space as "all structures" mod. "orientation-preserving diffeo's" (like the Tromba reference form above)? This should then simply...

Comment: result in two copies of the other notion of moduli space, right?

Comment: Consider reading, for instance "[An Introduction to Teichmüller Spaces](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Teichm%C3%BCller-Spaces-Yoichi-Imayoshi/dp/4431681760)" by Imayoshi and Taniguchi.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!